# How to define client side schema in `react-apollo` application?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am using `react-apollo` in my react applicant and I can't figure out how to implement a client side schema.

I have below type definition:

```
export const alertTypeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    alert: Alert
  }
  type Alert {
    message: String!
    type: String!
    duration: Int!
  }
`;
```

It defines a `Query` which returns an `alert` object.

Below is the code I want to use this query.

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

export const createClient = () => {
  return new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    typeDefs: [alertTypeDefs]
  });
};
```

First I initialised a `ApolloClient` instance with memory cache and `alertTypeDefs` defined above. Then below is the code to run the query:

```
const client = createClient();

const data = client.readQuery({query: gql`
  { 
    alert @client
  }
`});
console.log('data:', data);
```

But I got this error `Missing selection set for object of type Alert returned for query field alert` when run `readQuery` on the client instance. It seems that the `Alert` is not defined. But I already defined the `Alert` query in the `typeDefs`. It works fine if I change the query code to below which I have to specify what to be returned inside `{ message }`. But it doesn't seem to use the schema. What I expect is that I don't need to specify the return fields if it returns all fields in the schema object. Do I mis-understand the schema?

```
const data = client.readQuery({query: gql`
  { 
    alert @client {
      message
    }
  }
`});
console.log('data:', data);
```

If I have to specify the return fields one by one, what the point to define the schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior with GraphQL. You always need to specify inside the query which fields you're expecting. So in order to receive all the data you add the fields to the query:

```js
const data = client.readQuery({query: gql`
  { 
    alert @client {
      message
      type
      duration
    }
  }
`});
console.log('data:', data);
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/127) inside the GraphQL specs.

Comment: Is there a short cut to select all fields for an object? If I need this query in many places, I don't want to specify them one by one.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Check the issue for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `fragment` with all the fields of the entity and then reuse it.
Like this

```json
fragment AllAlertFields on Alert {
  message
  type
  duration
}
```

And then in a query

```json
query {
  allAlerts {
    ...AllAlertFields
  }  
}
```

More details: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/fragments/